# Detect different levels in in column

Tags: r

I do have a column with about 80k entries which has only 22 different levels (the number of the chromosome). Is there any quick trick in **R** to find out at which position a level changes into the next ... so to figure out at which row chromosome 1 changes to chromosome 2 ( all entries for a single chromosomes are listed together)?

My data looks like this:

```
chr number  marker name (SNP) 
1              rs...
1              rs...
.
.
2
```

thanks

Comment: Could you post an example of your data?

Answer (score 1):

Check for `diff` being nonzero.  This returns a logical vector which is `TRUE` when consecutive values aren't the same.  Wrap it with `which` to get numeric indicies.

```
(x <- factor(sample(c("a", "b"), 15, replace = TRUE)))
# [1] a a b b a a b b b b b a b a a
# Levels: a b
diff(as.integer(x)) != 0
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
which(diff(as.integer(x)) != 0)
# [1]  2  4  6 11 12 13
```

If all your chromosome values are grouped together, you can find the first instance of each level with `duplicated`.

```
(x2 <- factor(rep(c("a", "b", "c"), times = c(3, 4, 6))))
# [1] a a a b b b b c c c c c c
# Levels: a b c
!duplicated(x2)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
which(!duplicated(x2))
# [1] 1 4 8
```

Comment: how would that return me the precise value at which there is a switch in chromosomes?

Comment: @TimHeinert: Added more explanation for you, and an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unique` and `match` from `base` R:

```
data <- c(rep("a",10),rep("b",5),rep("c",2),rep("d",10))
match( unique(data) , data )
#[1]  1 11 16 18
```

Match returns a vector of the position of the *first* match of it's first argument in it's second argument. This works because all your entries for a chromosome are listed together.

Comment: in thsi case data woudl be just my first column wouln't it ?

Comment: @TimHeinert yes, exactly! So in your case `match( unique(mydata$chr) , mydata$chr )`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `rle` for this (if I get your question right):

```
x <- rep(LETTERS[1:22], each = 3)
x
# [1] "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "C" "C" "C" "D" "D" "D" "E" "E" "E" "F" "F" "F" "G" "G" "G" "H" "H" "H" #"I" "I" "I" "J" "J" "J" "K" "K" "K" "L" "L" "L" "M" "M" "M" "N" "N" "N" "O" "O" "O" "P" "P" "P" #"Q" "Q" "Q" "R" "R" "R" "S" "S" "S" "T" "T" "T" "U" "U" "U" "V" "V" "V"
rles <- rle(x)
cumsum(rles$lengths)
# [1]  3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36 39 42 45 48 51 54 57 60 63 66
```

Comment: hello, my problem is that the number of markers per chromosome are not constant, chr 1 has about 3k chr 2 more...does rle also work without the each argument ?

Comment: does this mean that cumsum(rles$lengths) would do the job? so that not each element needs to have the same length (such as 3 repetitions in your example)?

Comment: You provided no [reproducible example](tinyurl.com/reproducible-000), so I just made up an example. `x <- rep(LETTERS[1:22], each = 3)` is just generating example data - if your not happy with this, make up your own example in your question. `rle()` in combination with `cumsum()` are doing the job here, giving you the last position before a change.